# Rails: rendering the same piece of JSON by default

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on an API which returns JSON only.

All Exceptions/Errors are caught by an around_filter, and an appropriate JSON response is rendered from there.

Since all I want to return from my actions is a status, and all errors are handled by the around_filter, the last line of all my actions now looks like

`render :json => {:message => {:status => :ok}}`

Is there a way to tell rails to always render that line by default so that I don't have to add it to all my 274628 actions?

Comment: isnt status rendered as a default already? it should be

Comment: If I remove the render line, I'm getting 'Missing template jobpostings/destroy ...' (as there's indeed no template for the action, why would ther be) - I am pretty sure you have to render *something*

Comment: i meant you dont need to render status. but i see you're going to render for destroy, so you do need to render an ok. if it was another method that returned something, you don't need the status. something like render :json => @mymodel

Comment: Have you found a solution to this question? I have the exact same issue, always writing render :json ... Seems redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all your templates and render statements.

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from ActionView::MissingTemplate do |exception|
    # This will not work for partials
    render :json => {:message => {:status => :ok}}
  end
end

# some method in the controller
class PostController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json, :html, :xml

  def index
    puts "index"
  end
end
```

Personally, I would not do this.  If you really have 274,628 actions I would break up your app into smaller services (I know you are joking)  :) .  I just like being explicit about rendering even if it's more typing.  Also overriding defaults makes your app harder to explain and your code less clear.

I personally like the Grape API gem's design of default rendering.  You can mount a Grape API inside a rails app.  Maybe look at that for a cleaner solution.